# Hardening and securing Solaris 10 server

Tags: solaris

We have some Solaris 10 systems running on a SPARC. A former manager decided not to renew support contract with Oracle so we are missing some patches for the systems. Current management is working on getting a support contract but it may take a month or so. I see Vulnerability in the Oracle Solaris product of Oracle Systems (component: Pluggable authentication module) is getting exploited in the wild https://threatpost.com/oracle-solaris-zero-day-attack/160929/

The Solaris 10 systems are behind firewalls, do not have ports exposed to Internet, but don't have an anti-virus. They are pretty old, the former UNIX server admins retired and the current ones think installing an anti-virus can destabilize the system because of its age and not having current patches. We have a plan to retire them but it will take 6 months and budget approval.

I saw the SANS article https://www.sans.org/media/score/checklists/AuditingUnix.pdf and https://www.beyondtrust.com/blog/entry/harden-unix-linux-systems-close-security-gaps on hardening the UNIX servers.

1. Any other steps we need to take to secure the Solaris 10 systems?
2. Anything else we need to do to increase logging to detect any malicious activity?
3. Any other services which can help as we don't have an anti-virus on them currently?

Comment: I think this question belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: I would start by looking at the Solaris 10 STIG (Security Technical Information Guide).  You can download the manual or SCAP-enabled (Security Content Automation Protocol) version either from DISA or the NIST NVD (National Vulnerability Database).

Comment: @fpmurphy Thanks, I will look into that.